# How to store and recreate ECParameters?

Tags: .net, cryptography

I wish to store and recreate an instance of ECDsaCng so that I can create a digital signature using a private key on a web server and verify that digital signature using a public key in a desktop app. However, I'm having trouble understanding how to serialize the key data.

As a test, I have tried the following:

```
var ecDsaCng1 = new ECDsaCng();
var xmlString = ecDsaCng1.ToXmlString(ECKeyXmlFormat.Rfc4050);

var ecDsaCng2 = new ECDsaCng();
ecDsaCng2.FromXmlString(xmlString, ECKeyXmlFormat.Rfc4050);
```

However the second line throws an exception:

```
System.PlatformNotSupportedException
  Message=Operation is not supported on this platform.
  Source=System.Security.Cryptography.Cng
  StackTrace:
   at System.Security.Cryptography.ECDsaCng.ToXmlString(ECKeyXmlFormat format)
   [...]
```

This project is using .NET Core 3.1, however in production I will be using .NET Core 2.0 to create the signature.

I'm just unsure how to serialize and deserialize the ECDsaCng or ECParameters instances. I have limited permissions on the server so don't think I can use any data protection apis or similar.

Answer (score 0):

ECDsaCng I believe is a NET framework implementation; explore ECDsa.Create(...) and the associated ".ExportParameters(...)" method on the ECDsa object.